# Please don't mark as dupe without reading the full question!

Tags: discussion

I saw this in review: https://askubuntu.com/review/close/622277

That is **not** a dupe of the suggested question, because the OP's specific question is not answered: Can Ubuntu install successfully to EMMC storage?

Please read the full question before marking as dupe!

Comment: @MarkKirby - Ummm.... you do realize that you are suggesting the question is a dupe of **itself**?

Comment: My bad, I was in a rush and did not read it properly :) I am agreeing with you though, it is not a duplicate of that question. This one is close but no accept or votes http://askubuntu.com/questions/785121/installing-ubuntu-16-04-lte-on-emmc-storage

Comment: Fair enough, I've reopened it. It's not a dupe.